# Spring cloud sleuth for propagating baggage with otel configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin, open-telemetry

I am using spring cloud sleuth for propagating baggage with otel configuration. I want to send baggage with extra fields across applications. I am following this documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/3.1.1-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/project-features.html#features-baggage

This is working fine with sleuth brave but with spring-cloud-sleuth-otel it seems some extra configuration is required. Please suggest where I can get related information.

Comment: I got it here for Producer:https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-sleuth-samples/blob/main/baggage-producer/   For Consumer: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-sleuth-samples/tree/main/baggage-consumer